# Writing logs to console for windows service while in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, nlog

I am developing a windows service. When I am in debug mode I want to write logs to console window instead of file. I am using `nlog` library to write logs. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to this question by my self, I came to know that i have to add target and logger like below

Target

```
<target xsi:type="Console" name="console"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"/>
```

Logger Code

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
```